# Caps on a screw

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make caps for a circle mesh that I modify into a screw. I'm very new to blender and have watched a few videos but either the version is old or I'm doing it wrong.

I also tried to add a bevel circle to a spiral but the circle mesh does not appear in the possible bevel list.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some screen captures or your blend file in order to understand better your question ? To share a blend file you can use : http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1491" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1491/)

Comment: Thanks... could you also indicate what you means by "caps" here ? Or a link to the videos you are talking about ? Or do you want to close the "tube" ?

Comment: I am a bit surprised, but it seems that closing the tube is not possible. Can you give a link to the videos ?

Comment: I figured it out. I was not applying the modifier, so I did not have the faces and vertices available in edit mode. once I applied the modifier to the circle I was able to select the vertices around the openings and use F to fill

Comment: ok. Thanks for the information. Just to know : the screew tool in the tools panel (edit mode) allows to screw closed faces and so the result is caped

Answer (score 2):

1. Enter object mode
2. Apply the screw modifier
3. Enter Edit mode and select your screw
4. Push F to fill

Answer (score 1):

Frank answered his own question in the comments : to cap a shape constructed with the "screw modifier", you have to apply this modifier and cap the extremities manually.

But I allow myself to post an answer because the "screw modifier" behavior is a bit strange (at least I did not expected this).

Here from top to bottom :

- A open circle : all is normal but not capped
- A circle with one face (select all then <kbd>F</kbd>) : the face does not appear, and the smooth does not work anymore
- A circle with n faces (select all then extrude, scale to zero and remove doubles) : the edges are extruded by the modifier

[image]

For information, the screw tool of the tools panel in edit mode does not have the same behavior and allows face extrusion. So you can screw a plain circle and obtain directly a caped spiral.